# "APC does not appear to be running"

Tags: server, php

Help!

1. I'm a Linux newbie. I have a VPS with Ubuntu 12.04.5 on it.
2. It came with PHP 5.3. I've successfully installed PHP 5.4.37 **as additional PHP handler** following this tutorial: http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/118378
3. I've installed APC following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-alternative-php-cache-apc-on-a-cloud-server-running-ubuntu-12-04

When I choose PHP 5.3 in Plesk then it works. But when I choose 5.4.37 then apc.php shows:

> No cache info available. APC does not appear to be running.

How can I get APC running under PHP 5.4?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you can either change the directory or just move the apc.so file from it's directory to the one specified in PHP.ini file.

Comment: Which directory do you mean?

Comment: the directory specified in this file:  /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Comment: What do you mean by saying "you can either change the directory"? There is no php.ini in /usr/local/lib

Comment: Well then your install did not go correctly please try un installiing it using this command:

sudo apt-get remove --purge [nameofinstallhere]

then run: 

sudo apt-get install php5